# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} i^n$ is unconditionally convergent.

Tags: calculus

The problem I have is I don't see at which point I'm making a mistake. Since absolute convergence implies unconditional convergence, I want to show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} i^n|$$
converges. But
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} i^n| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|(-1)^{n-1}|}{|n|} |i^n| = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \to \infty.$$

Comment: Well if $i$ is indeed the complex such that $i^2=-1$ then there is nothing to do, it's effectively not absolutely convergent. Maybe $i$ stands for something else, in this case $\sum i^n/n$ is ACV for $|i|<1$, but this is doubtful. The problem seems wrong.

Comment: Converges at $\log(1+i)$ but not absolutely

Comment: I took the problem from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lOpAVZUQGJ4. At 16:30, he changes the order of summation, something you can do only if a series is unconditionally convergent. Am I missing something or is his approach incorrect?

Comment: @DumbDumb Conditional convergence means that you can't rearrange the series and expect it automatically to sum to the right number. It doesn't mean that every change will affect the result (e.g. you can swap the first two terms in any series, and it will converge to the same result). In this case, you're right that a step was skipped, but the calculation is valid. In particular, he's deinterlacing the real and imaginary parts to get two (conditionally) convergent series. You can always interlace two convergent series to get a convergent series!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In $ \mathbb C$, unconditional convergence is equivalent to absolut convergence.
2. If $a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} i^n$, then $|a_n|= \frac{1}{n} .$

Hence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} i^n$ is not  unconditionally convergent !